# Receiving album art in android 11

Tags: java, android, kotlin, thumbnails

As [known](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns#ALBUM_ART), ALBUM_ART was deprecated in Android 11. Google says that [ContentResolver.loadThumbnail](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#loadThumbnail(android.net.Uri,%20android.util.Size,%20android.os.CancellationSignal)) should be used instead. But i totally don't understand how to use it, especially what i should provide as first parameter, uri. Documentation says:

> Uri: The item that should be visualized as a thumbnail. This value cannot be null.

What is that item and how can I get it? Is this Uri of the music file?

Comment: You will have tried by now so you could tell us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in the Uri of the track.

```
//This will get you the uri of the track, if you already have the track id
Uri trackUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, trackId);
Bitmap bm = contentResolver.loadThumbnail(trackUri, new Size(512,512), null);
```

Set the bitmap to an ImageView

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Comment: Ait is working, thanks. but unfortunately, Picasso cannot load Bitmaps from the box. Is it the way to get Uri of the thumbnail?

Comment: What is the track id?